# Using sed to change beginning char with another

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

Can i re-insert a number using sed?

i need to sed to read a input and if it starts with a number, replace it with square brackets and the number

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This should work with any sed:

```
sed 's/^[0-9]\{1,\}/[&]/' file
```

or

```
sed 's/^[0-9][0-9]*/[&]/' file
```

Comment: +1. As an explanation, the `&` character in the replacement text will be substituted by whatever was matched by the regex. ([manual reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command))